# URL design for GET resource in REST API for images

Tags: rest, amazon-s3

I have a Rest API that allows users to POST to an endpoint to upload a photo:

```
POST /api/photos
```

The response would be as follows:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "my image"
  "url": "https://some_s3_url"
}
```

The user can then access the photo metadata through the GET endpoint

```
GET /api/photos/1
```

What is the best way to model a url for getting the content of the image url? Note that I'd like to ensure the user has the ability to access this image, so requesting the s3 bucket url directly will not work here.

I have considered doing something like:

```
GET /api/photos/1/content
```

Though that seemed hacky

Comment: Intuitive to me: `GET /api/photos/1` → image; `GET /api/photos/1/metadata` → metadata.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm a bit concerned that the unintuitive part might be that `GET /api/photos` should return a list of metadata and `POST` and `DELETE` operations would modify the resource. But overall I agree with you that this is a good approach

Answer (score 1):

first of all POST request should not return response, it could return header called `location` to return URI of created resource for ex. `http://youer-server/api/photos/1` then in GET request for this URL you can return the json object as:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "my image",
  "url": "https://some_s3_url",
  "base64": .....
}
```

then you can encode your image as base64 and provide its content in the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though in this case does it not make sense to use s3 if I'm duplicating the information in the base64 encoding?

Comment: based on your design, if you want to provide both options you can put both, or you can use projection